# Unable to cast object of type 'System.Linq.EnumerableQuery`1[Entities.Test]' to type 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1[Entities.Test]'

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, ef-code-first

I'm using Entity Framework 4.2 (EntityFramework.dll v4.0.30319) Code First and have a LINQ query which can be simplified to:

```
IQueryable<Test> testQuery = from test in repository.Tests select test;
```

The `repository.Tests` is `IQueryable<Test>` implemented directly as `DbSet<Test>` in Enity Framework's `DbContext`.

I noticed that my queries are somehow case-sensitive with case-insensitive collation in Microsoft SQL Server Database. Suspicious, so I wanted to trace the SQL. But when I do this:

```
var trace = ((ObjectQuery<Test>)testQuery).ToTraceString();
```

I get exception:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Linq.EnumerableQuery`1[Entities.Test]' to type 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1[Entities.Test]'.

Why this happens?

Comment: Just in case anybody googled this: queries acted case-sensitive because this was executed in unit test with mocked data (array, not DB). ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are combining two different APIs - ObjectContext API and DbContext API. You cannot cast query created from `DbSet` to `ObjectQuery` but only to `DbQuery` which is not related to `ObjectQuery`.

What you want to do can be easily achived by:

```
var trace = testQuery.ToString();
```